# Express $-X$ and $X-Y$ with characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent identical distributions with characteristic function $\varphi$. Express the characteristic functions of $-X$ and $X-Y$ with $\varphi$

My attempt:

I know that $\varphi_X(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})$ and that $\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2)$ if $X_1, X_2$ are independent.

Knowing that, I can compute
$$\varphi_{X-Y}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{it(X-Y)})=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX}e^{-itY})\overset{?}{=}\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})\mathbb{E}(e^{-itY})=\varphi_X(t)\varphi_{-Y}(t)$$

I am not 100% sure about the third step (marked with a "?"). I know that measurable functions of independent variables are also independent and that $exp$ is borel-measurable, but maybe the $i$ makes a difference?

Moving on to $\varphi_{-X}$
$$\varphi_{-X}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{it(-X)})=\mathbb{E}(e^{i(-t)X})=\varphi_{X}(-t)$$
Same thing with $\varphi_{-Y}$, so I can simplify $\varphi_{X-Y}$ even further so that $\varphi_{X-Y}(t)=\varphi_X(t)\varphi_{Y}(-t)$

Now I've expressed both characteristic functions with $\varphi_X$ and $\varphi_Y$

Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Second part is perfect. First part there is a slight mistake: you should express $it(-Y)$ instead of $-itY$ but the rest is perfect. As you correctly pointed out, if you have two independent RVs then $E f(X)g(Y)=E f(X) Eg(Y)$ for any measurable functions $f$ and $g$ and $i$ does not make any difference. In fact, moving to the complex world makes things easier! Good job!

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera Thank you!!